# PHP: remove element from multidimensional array (by key) using foreach

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, unset

I got multidimensional array. From each subarray, I would like to remove / unset values with index 1. My array $data.

```
Array
(
    [3463] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2014
            [context] => 'aaa'
        )

    [3563] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => 2014
            [context] => 'aaa'
        )       

    [2421] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 2014
            [context] => 'zzz'
        )               
)
```

I would like to remove every element with index '1' from subarrays. Desired output is:

```
Array
(
    [3463] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [context] => 'aaa'
        )

    [3563] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [context] => 'aaa'
        )       

    [2421] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [context] => 'zzz'
        )               
)
```

Why this does not work?

```
foreach ($data as $subArr) {
   foreach ($subArr as $key => $value) {
       if ($key == '1') {
        unset($subArr[$key]);
       }

   }
}
```

I'm sorry if this problem is trivial for you guys.

Comment: it is because foreach makes a copy of the element and does not work on the original array you can avoid this by assigning by reference. In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede $subArr with &. In that case the value will be assigned by reference.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

easy way!?
you can do this just  with one foreach!

```
foreach ($data as $key => $subArr) {
    unset($subArr['1']);
    $data[$key] = $subArr;  
}
```

Comment: `foreach ($data as $key => &$subArr) unset($subArr['1']);`

Answer (score 11):

you are making changes in subarray instead of main one try this may help

```
foreach ($data as $key => $subArr) { 
    unset($data[$key][1]);      
}
```

Answer (score 10):

It does not work because `$subArr` from the outer `foreach` contains **copies** of the values of `$data` and the inner `foreach` modifies these copies, leaving `$data` not touched.

You can fix that by telling `PHP` to make `$subArr` references to the original values stored in `$data`:

```
foreach ($data as &$subArr) {
   foreach ($subArr as $key => $value) {
       if ($key == '1') {
        unset($subArr[$key]);
       }
   }
}
```

Another option is to use function [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php). It uses a callback function that can inspect (and modify) each value of `$data` and it returns a new array.

```
$clean = array_map(
    function (array $elem) {
        unset($elem['1']);        // modify $elem
        return $elem;             // and return it to be put into the result
    },
    $data
);

print_r($clean);
```

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
<?php 
    $data = Array
    (
        '3463' => Array
            (
                '0' => 1,
                '1' => 2014,
                'context' => 'aaa'
            ),

        '3563' => Array
            (
                '0' => 12,
                '1' => 2014,
                'context' => 'aaa'
            ),       

        '2421' => Array
            (
                '0' => 5,
                '1' => 2014,
                'context' => 'zzz'
            )               
    );

    foreach ($data as $k=>$subArr) {
        foreach ($subArr as $key => $value) {

            if ($key == '1') {
                unset($data[$k][$key]);
            }

        }
    }
print_r($data);// display the output
```