# Rejecting certain index parameters in an array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent

Given an array, in which each index there are certain key value pairs, how do I select certain key value pairs and reject the others.

```
$channels = Channel::get()->toArray();
```

This will yield the following Array:

```
"channels": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Info Release",
        "slug": "info-release",
        "desc": "Contains blah blah.",
        "access_level": "0",
        "created_at": "2018-12-02 01:23:50",
        "updated_at": "2018-12-05 07:54:41"
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "Casual News",
        "slug": "casual-news",
        "desc": "Contains blah blah.",
        "access_level": "0",
        "created_at": "2018-12-05 05:34:50",
        "updated_at": "2018-12-05 07:54:32"
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "haha",
        "slug": "haha",
        "desc": "Contains blah blah.",
        "access_level": "0",
        "created_at": "2018-12-29 23:27:16",
        "updated_at": "2018-12-29 23:27:16"
    }
],
```

What is the best way to turn that array into this:

```
"channels": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Information Release",
        "slug": "information-release",
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "Casual News",
        "slug": "casual-news",
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "haha",
        "slug": "haha",
    }
],
```

So that if I write

```
$channels[0]->id
```

it will spit out `1`

Comment: can't you just ignore them?

Comment: @tim It's being passed to the frontend via an api endpoint and I wouldn't want that data to be local.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: remove element from multidimensional array (by key) using foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27482851/php-remove-element-from-multidimensional-array-by-key-using-foreach)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can You try this

```
$viewFileds = ['id', 'name', 'slug'];

$channels = Channel::get()
                    ->map(function ($each) use ($viewFileds) {
                        return Arr::only($each, $viewFileds);
                    });
```

It will return the new Collection by Only the field enabled in the `$viewFileds`

Hope it helps

Comment: This is great! Thank you!